# Distance between pairs of points in a cartesian plane

Tags: algorithm, geometry

I was recently asked the following question, in a Foursquare interview. I was not able to code this.

We are given N points (xi,yi) where 1<=i<=N,  and two numbers a and b,such that distance between two points (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) is max(a*|x1-x2|,b*|y1-y2|), how can we calculate sum of distances between each pair of points?

The number of points N is a high number.

Can anyone help with how to solve this question? Please explain the algorithm, other than the brute force one of traversing on all pairs of points.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how you couldn't get this to go.  Can't you simply iterate through each pair of points, calculate the `max(...)` statement and sum up all of the `max(...)` calls?

Comment: That is brute force. I look for a better algorithm. Obviously I could think of that.

Comment: Did they ask you for a brute force algorithm or any algorithm?  Brute force is better than giving nothing.

Comment: Now your situation has changed.  You didn't mention that the amount of points would be high.

Comment: They asked for the best optimal algorithm, and not the Brute force.

Comment: @rayryeng Yes I mentioned that. My bad. Sorry.

Comment: That's fine.  Now your problem is a lot more interesting!

Comment: Shouldn't this question be on http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry ?

Comment: @KonstantinV.Salikhov It was a programming question. I was asked to code it. I think this is the suitable place.

Comment: @KonstantinV.Salikhov - This particular question is a fine-line... it's certainly an algorithmic question but it also falls under mathematics as well.  I think it's on topic.

Comment: Maybe some clever shoelace formula?

Comment: I am trying to think of a solution for a simpler problem. If all the points are in a straight horizontal or vertical line, then it can be done in O(n) time. Did you try reducing this problem to a simpler version in the interview? Or maybe the interviewer gave some help?

Comment: I'm looking forward to the answers here.  This is an interesting problem.  BTW, my comment regarding brute force was merited because the OP did not include the fact that the number of points was high and that brute force was not an option in the original version of the question.

Comment: @NikunjBanka I was asked to code it. No help given. :(

Comment: @zch I was considering the fact that the points were given in sorted order. But that won't be always true. So O(nlogn) including the sorting part.

Answer (score 6):

Start by rescaling the axis, to get rid of `a` and `b` factors. Define `x' = a * x, y' = b * y'`. Then the distance is:

```
max(a*|x1-x2|,b*|y1-y2|) =
max(|a*x1-a*x2|,|b*y1-b*y2|) =
max(|x'1-x'2|,|y'1-y'2|)
```

Secondly, rotate the coordinate system by 45 degrees, to change it to [Taxicab geometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry). Define `s = (x' + y')/2, t = (x' - y')/2`. Then we have `x' = s + t, y' = s - t`.

Then we can rewrite definition of the distance again:

```
max(|x'1-x'2|,|y'1-y'2|) =
max(|s1 + t1 - s2 - t2|,|s1 - t1 - s2 + t2|) =
max(|(s1 - s2) + (t1 - t2)|,|(s1 - s2) - (t1 - t2)|) =
|s1 - s2| + |t1 - t2|
-- last equation comes from the fact that max(|a + b|, |a - b|) = |a| + |b|
```

With this definition we can separately sum distances along `s` axis and separately along `t` axis and add the results.

Solving one-dimensional version of this problem is quite simple. You sort the points along the axis. Then each segment between (0-based) `i`-th and `i+1`-th point will contribute `(i + 1) * (N - i - 1) * distance`. It's enough to sum these values.

Overall solution takes `O(n lg n)`, since it need to sort points two times.

Comment: I don't understand your solution for the 1D problem. Do you take i: [0..n-1] or [1..n]? I don't get there with either. Take 3 points (1,0),(2,0),(3,0), A=1,B=0: total distance should be 4. according to your formula: `1*(3-1-1)*1+2*(3-2-1)*1 = 1` for i=[1..3] or `0*(3-0-1)*1+1*(3-1-1)*1 = 1` for i=[0..2].

Comment: Great solution, upvoted!! But I will try to learn something here. The key was the replacement for s and t here. How did you come up with the substitution s=(x+y)/2 and t=(x-y)/2 ? Is it common in geometry questions? <br>And also how is it related to taxicab geometry and rotating the axis by 45 degrees, because then the new point would have been something else? (Apply the formula s = xcosQ - ysinQ, t = xsinQ+ycosQ)

Comment: @Wouter, corrected the formula, I was off by one. There are `i + 1` points on the left of the segment and `N - i - 1` points on the right, so there will be `(i + 1) * (N - i - 1)` pairs of points that contain this segment.

Comment: @NikunjBanka, if you draw points with distance `1` from some point you get square in maximum metric and diamond in taxicab metric, so I knew that I can transform one to other by rotating. Luckily, `sin 45 = cos 45` and I don't care about preserving scale, so I use 1/2 just because it makes equations easy.

Answer (score 1):

We want to compute

```
sum_i sum_j max(a |xi - xj|, b |yi - yj|).
```

Simplify the problem by mapping `xi' = a xi` and `yi' = b yi` and computing

```
sum_i sum_j max(|xi' - xj'|, |yi' - yj'|).
```

Simplify the problem by mapping `ui = (xi + yi)/2` and `vi = (xi - yi)/2` and computing

```
sum_i sum_j (|ui - uj| + |vi - vj|)
    = sum_i sum_j |ui - uj| + sum_i sum_j |vi - vj|.
```

To solve the first subproblem in time O(n log n), here's some Python.

```
def one_d(us):
    us = sorted(us)
    return sum((2 * i - (len(us) - 1)) * u for (i, u) in enumerate(us))
```